# How do I install the driver for a Microsoft Lifecam VX-3000?

Tags: software-installation, webcam

I have looked all over Ask Ubuntu and can't find any way to install the driver easily. I will be fine by doing it through terminal if that is how to do it.

Comment: Is there a Linux driver for that webcam?

Comment: What happens when you plug it in?

Comment: related forum thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1860212

Comment: i think this post is realy useful for this question -> https://burgerminds.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/microsoft-lifecam-vx-3000-and-gnulinux/

Answer (score 10):

## Driver

The driver for this webcam is already included, and it should work out of the box. You can check if it does with `cheese`.

The kernel module for this webcam is called `gspca_sonixj`. You can check if it's loaded with:

```
lsmod | grep sonixj
```

### Skype

#### Testing if it works

If the webcam does work in **Cheese** but not in **Skype**, that's because this webcam can only output JPEG compressed frames which Skype cannot handle. To fix this, the proposed solution of the other answers is already *almost* correct.

---

Start Skype from a Terminal window by running:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skype
```

or if you're on a 64bit system (if output of `uname -m` is `x86_64`):

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skype
```

---

In **Ubuntu 11.10** the path changed, so for 32bit use

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skype
```

and for 64bit use

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skype
```

---

In **Ubuntu 12.04** the path for **64bit** changed *again*, so use

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skype
```

For 32bit see above.

#### Making it permanent

If this works, you can change the Menu entry similar to how @demua suggests doing:

- copy `/usr/share/applications/skype.desktop` to a file in your Profile to prevent future updates from undoing your changes. This can be done in a Terminal with:

  ```
  mkdir -p $HOME/.local/share/applications
  cp /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop $HOME/.local/share/applications/
  ```
- open the newly created `$HOME/.local/share/applications/skype.desktop` in an editor and change the line

  ```
   Exec=skype
  ```

  to something like

  ```
   Exec=env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skype
  ```

  Of course you have to use the same path here as above when testing.

---

The workaround for Skype also works for other legacy applications and other webcams that only support unusual formats. Tested with:

- Microsoft VX-3000
- Hercules Deluxe Optical Glass

Comment: Great response and perfect fix, I've used this several times on multiple occasions and keep it bookmarked. Thank you!

Comment: It works with `cheese` just as bseibold says. March 2018, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the LifeCam VX-5000

Comment: Next step will be to try `motion` as per https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-motion-detection-webcam-ubuntu/

Answer (score 6):

Your webcam should work out of the box in 11.10. What are the outputs of these commands?

```
lsusb | grep LifeCam
sudo lsmod | grep v4l1_compat
```

Make sure video for linux is installed

```
#32-bit
sudo apt-get install libv4l-0

#64-bit
sudo apt-get install libv4l-0 lib32v4l-0
```

Skype may not detect the camera however. To solve that issue, force skype to load the v4l library like so:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

Comment: `lsusb | grep LifeCam` shows the VX-5000 very clearly.  March 2018 Ubuntu 16.04, full-motion video by default in `cheese`.  Excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

Skype

http://www.ubunturoot.com/2010/05/how-to-fix-webcam-problem-in-skype.html

uninstall `libavcodec53` and

install `xubuntu restricted extras`

Then commands

```
echo -e "\n# libv4l PPA\ndeb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libv4l/ppa/ubuntu `lsb_release -c | awk '{print $2}'` main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com C3FFB4AA

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libv4l-0
    LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype

bash -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype'
```

First trz to edit in the launcher the command and put

```
bash -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

worked for me

If you are using Ubuntu 11.04 and Unity or other desktop environment, Menu Editor is not available. To edit launcher in Unity you need to edit Skype.desktop

So start terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
```

Now edit in line 4, replace;

```
Exec=skype
```

with:

```
Exec=bash -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are issues getting that particular webcam to work correctly on Ubuntu, after a fair bit of looking around I found [this info on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8569519) that may solve your problem - good luck.

Comment: I looked at that and that's for a different version of Ubuntu. Have any other ideas?

Comment: I want to do it on skype and it shows the webcam, but won't test it or let me view it.

Comment: @Alexander - the forum post may relate to a different version of Ubuntu but did you try it? I've got little experience getting web cams to work, my Microsoft one simply plugs in and works...

Comment: It works out of the box with v16.04 LTS and `cheese`  - March 2018