# Webcam keeps blinking for no reason

Tags: webcam

I have a [Microsoft LifeCam VX-700](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002JXKGFA) webcam, and it was working okay until yesterday when it started blinking for no reason.

I haven't changed any settings, or even used it recently.

And now it comes and goes, without me doing anything.

Could this be caused by a software update that was released recently?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Can you test it on another PC?

Comment: I don't have access to another PC, but it doesn't do that on Windows 7, so it's not a hardware thing.

Comment: Enter this command in a Terminal: tail -f /var/log/syslog then plug in your webcam. To you get any output? See also this http://askubuntu.com/questions/73357/how-do-i-install-the-driver-for-a-microsoft-lifecam-vx-3000

Answer (score 1):

If it starts blinking when you access flash in Google Chrome, it might be caused by a bug in their Pepper-based Flashplayer. To fix it, go to **about:plugins** in Chrome, click **+Details** to expand all items, then disable the plugin **/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so**. Leave the regular libflashplayer.so plugin enabled, or install it if you need to. Should stop the blinking.

Comment: Your solution fixes the webcam problem, but then it deteriorates flash in chrome. Before your solution I was able to watch full screen videos on youtube in a relatively fluent way, after the fix it was back to the old chopped ways I knew before I used Chrome (the fact that only Chrome continues flash development on Linux was the reason I moved from chromium to Chrome in the first place, so if the webcam fix breaks flash, unfortunately that doesn't solve it for me). I filed a bug report today: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adobe-flashplugin/+bug/1046921